# USB Flash Drive folders not opening but a command exe.corrupt appears

Tags: windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

Whenever i try to open the folders in my USB Flash Drive on my laptop with windows 8, it says EXE corrupted.  How to open the folders?

Comment: Does it happen on other machines too with the same USB Flash device ? This might clarify if the problem resides in Windows or on the USB device.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the "View" tab in Windows Explorer, select "File name extensions". 
   If it is already selected, something serious is going on in your PC.

2. Again select View and now checkmark "Hidden Items". If any hidden folders show up, try to open them, those might be what you are looking for in your pen drive.
3. If Step 2 is successful , please run an Anti-virus scan. Your pen drive might be affected by a virus.